# Unsubscribe from campaign Exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to accomplish this from email sends from Exact Target " Whenever email recipient receives email of a campaign, he/she should have the option to click on unsubscribe link which will unsubscribe the person ***only from that specific campaign*** and not all the mails from the org "

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign [Publication Lists](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/publication_lists/) in your email send definitions to ensure granularity in your unsubscribes.  That is assuming you're using the standard unsub [personalization string](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/) for the link.

If you're using a custom preference center, you must [log the unsub event properly](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/server_side_javascript_sample_code/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call/).